# Inconsistent page redirections in php 

Tags: php

I have set the session on all pages in my admin panel like so:

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
   header("Location: login.php?e=please+login+first");
```

This seemed to be working properly on all my pages, but now when I refresh my page or click on a link, the page automatically redirects to `login.php`. This seems to happen infrequently. I don't understand what is causing this problem

As an example, my menu bar is like:

```
home : doctors: hospitals:  feedback
```

If I am on `hospitals.php`, then after a few mins I click on `feedback.php` (or any other link) I get redirected to `login.php`. The next time if I again click on the link I will not get redirected

Here is my dologin.php code

```
$qry = "select * from admin where username='$uname' and password='$pwd'";
//echo $qry;exit;
$rs = mysql_query($qry,$con);
if($rec= mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
  $_SESSION['username'] = $rec['username'];
    header("Location: index.php");
}
 else if (empty($uname))
{
     header("Location: login.php?e=Please+enter+username");
}
 else
 {
     header("Location: login.php?e=Invalid+username+or+password");
 }
```

Comment: Have you forgot a `session_start();` on top of your dologin.php page?

Comment: no.. i have already put session_start(); on dologin.php @adrien

Comment: I'm surprised nobody's launched into a lecture on sql injection yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:
Replace your query:

```
$qry = "select * from admin where username='$uname' and password='$pwd'";
```

With this:

```
$qry = "select * from admin where username='" . $uname . "' and password='" . $pwd . "'";
```

Also replace your:

```
session_start();
```

with:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
```

**Recommendations:** I would also recommend placing the content that is being reused from file to file in a PHP include such as header.php.

**PS:** try accepting more answers, it helps motivate people to answer your questions. Also keeps the community alive.

Comment: thans you @karl. should i replace this `session` code in all my pages or only in dologin.php

Comment: I would recommend always using the if statement around your session_start, not necessary though, it's just proper coding. Look up how to use PHP includes, it will prevent you from repeating yourself. Also don't forget to accept my answer if it worked. Good luck with your app!

Comment: You have to click the check mark below the up and down arrow to accept the answer. If you click the up arrow it just gives preference to this particular answer but doesnt accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try calling session_write_close() before you redirect with header to make sure the session is closed.

Comment: how to use this.. please i am new. could you please tell where to put this code

Comment: something like this:
$_SESSION["username"] = $something;
session_write_close();
Header("Location: $url");
exit();